# Textsubscript is like the character underscore

Tags: symbols

when to use textsubscript and when to use _

**question 1:**
Which of them is advisable to use to write mathematical formulas?

**question 2** i want written the next image

[image]

Comment: `\textsubscript` should make the the subscript look like text rather than math. See the difference: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x_i$ vs. $x\textsubscript{i}$
\end{document}`. When to use each? It depends on what you want the output to look like...

Comment: It's simple: *never* use `\textsubscript` in math mode.

Comment: @egreg then i should textsubscript on text mode?

Comment: your question is less clear than it was. Originally you asked about use in formulae but now you show something that is out of context is that in text, or a subscripted variable in math or ?

Answer (score 6):

`\textsubscript` should almost never be used. It is just added for symmetry with `\textsuperscript` which is used for footnote markers etc, and the point of the commands is that they are *not* math mode so never use either in math.

Comment: when should a mathematical formula be written in a paragraph?

Comment: i edited my question